# выборка сегментов строки с помощью регулярки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

ребят помогите с регулярками на js

есть строка `right-wide-inside.png`

у нее 3 сегмента неизвестной длины

```
right
wide
inside
```

гарантировано в строке есть первый и второй дефис и точка, длина сегментов и расширения неизвестны

надо 3 регулярки для функции test.replace() которые будут заменять эти 3 сегмента, например right на left, wide на long, inside на outside

**Частичное решение:**
первые 2 варианта написал, последний не дается

1. /^[^-]*-/
2. /-.*-/
3. ???

Answer (score 2):

Если три раздельных, то так:

```js
let sSource = 'right-wide-inside.png';

console.log( sSource.replace(/^[a-z]+(.*)$/, 'left$1') );
console.log( sSource.replace(/^(.*-)[a-z]+(-.*)$/, '$1long$2') );
console.log( sSource.replace(/^(.*-)+[a-z]+(\..*)$/, '$1outside$2') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const initString = 'right-wide-inside.png';

const [_, right, wide, inside] = initString.match(/(\w+)\-(\w+)\-(\w+)\.(\w+)?/);
```

Comment: не, надо отдельно 3 регулярки, у меня задача такова, что в каждую замену, есть только либо первый, либо второй либо 3 сегмент. всех сразу нет

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи

1. `/^[^-]*-/`
2. `/-.*-/`
3. `/(.*)-(.*)-.*\.(.*)/`